# How to set media_folder and public_folder in Netlify CMS when not using static site generator?

Tags: javascript, yaml, markdown, netlify-cms

I’m connecting Netlify CMS to a website built without a static site generator.

In my config.yml I have **media_folder: “/images/uploads”**. At the moment I’m using **public_folder: “/images/uploads”** in config.yml which should, to my understanding, add /images/uploads as the path to the image in the index.md.

The problem is that whatever I write in public_folder the image will always be found at images/uploads/imagename.png, but the path to the image in the markdown file is always image/imagename.png.

Any guidance on what I do wrong here?

### config.yml

```
backend:

    name: git-gateway

    branch: main # Branch to update (optional; defaults to master)

media_folder: "/images/uploads" # Media files will be stored in the repo under images/uploads

public_folder: "/images/uploads"

collections:

    - label: "Pages"

      name: "pages"

      files:

      - file: "_posts/news/index.md"

        label: "News" # Used in the UI

        name: "news" # Used in routes, e.g., /admin/collections/blog

        description: "News page"

        fields: # The fields for each document, usually in front matter

          - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "news-page"}

          - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}

          - {label: Description, name: description, widget: string}

          - {label: Intro, name: intro, widget: object, fields: [{label: Blurbs, name: blurbs, widget: list, fields: [{label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}, {label: Body, name: body, widget: markdown}, {label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime"}]}]}
```

### index.md

```
---

title: Aktuellt

description: "Aktuella händelser.. "

intro:

  blurbs:

    - date: 2020-10-15T10:23:49.470Z

      title: Hej

      body: Test

      image: images/newspaper.jpg

---
```

### Fetch response in frontend

As you can see the address returned by fetch is image/newspaper.jpg. In reality it is images/uploads/newspaper.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it myself, after a long walk. I just had to delete index.md and add content again in the CMS admin interface.

So, steps to solve the issue:

- one long walk
- delete index.md
- add content with CMS admin interface.

Comment: Wow that was unexpected. After trying out everything I could in other ways to fix this, I luckily found your solution. I deleted my whole content folder with all markdown files and surprise, finally the changes to public_folder and media_folder were respected by Netlify. Thanks!